# Are EJB 3.1 Interceptors "blockers"?

Tags: java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

it's my first post here!

I'm new in Java EE dev and what i want to know is if an Interceptor can block the normal flow of execution.

What i want implement is a sort of "observer" bean: suppose that i have a bean that perform an update in the db, called from the web layer. I would like that another bean is called after the update in an asyncronous way to do something else, in my case send an email with JavaMail, without blocking the normal flow of the first bean, i.e. give back control to who call the first bean.

My idea is to intercept some session ejb method: from that interceptor I whould like to call some other ejbs, like a singleton ejb.
Is the right approach? I should use something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what the interceptors are for. The client invokes some method on your EJB and you define what interceptors should intercept this call.

In the interceptor method you can decide what to do with the request - either it can proceed to the next interceptor in the chain (or the real endpoint - your EJB - if this is the last interceptor) or it can block the execution.

In the intercepting method you have access to the [InvocationContext](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/InvocationContext.html) on which you must explicitely call **proceed()** method in order to proceed with the request. Not calling this method is plainly blocking the invocation.

HTH.